# Inverting a block matrix with particular structure

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, block-matrices

I would like to find a simple way to compute the inverse of a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{(N+1)\times(N+1)}$ given by

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}3D_1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 &  1 \\
0 & 3D_2 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 3D_N & 1 \\
1 & 1 &1 & \dots & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix},$$

where $D_1, \dots, D_N$ are strictly positive constant terms.

On Wikipedia, I found something like the following. However, I am looking for something simpler.

---

[image]

Comment: Could you be more precise on what confuses you? The capital letters for the scalars $D_i$?

Comment: Yes. If you want to use uppercase for scalars, better write the matrices in bold uppercase.

Comment: I see, sorry I didn't pay attention to that.

Comment: My point is that these details make it easier to do mental type-checks.  In programming, one can write `x :: Integer`, but in mathematical notation, it would be better to use just $n$, since $x$ is usually for reals, $\bf X$ would be a matrix, $\mathcal X$ would be a set, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity)
$$
\left(A + UCV \right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U \left(C^{-1} + VA^{-1}U \right)^{-1} VA^{-1}
$$
with
$$
A = \pmatrix{3D_1 \\ &\ddots \\ && 3D_n\\ &&& -1}, \quad 
U = \pmatrix{1&0\\\vdots&\vdots\\1&0\\1&1}, \quad 
V = \pmatrix{0&\cdots&0&1\\1&\cdots&1&0},
$$
and $C = I$ (where $I$ denotes the $2\times 2$ identity matrix).

Comment: You mean the identity in $\mathbb{R}^2$ right?

Comment: @ofir_13 Yes, that's correct